# Agregar metodo onhover de JQuery a varios elementos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Quisiera hacer un onhover para agregar una clase que activa un efecto de animación sobre el objeto al cual se lo tiro, pero no lo consigo , esto es lo que tengo.

tengo una serie de `<a>` que tienen de clase anchor-lbl , utilicé algo similar para asignarles una clase a todos, pero ahora quiero asignarles una clase. Supongo que necesito algo similar

```js
! function() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("lbl2");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].classList.add('animated', 'bounceInLeft');
  }

}();



! function() {
  $(".lbl2").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('bounceInLeft');
    $(this).addClass('bounce');
  }).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('bounce');
  });
}();
```

```html
<label class="lbl">Monto Crédito </label>
<a class="anchor-lbl" href="#">
  <h3 class="lbl2">$7,000.00 hasta $60,000.00</h3>
</a>
<label class="lbl">Plazo Mínimo </label>
<a class="anchor-lbl" href="#">
  <h3 class="lbl2">3.5 Meses</h3>
</a>
<label class="lbl">Plazo Máximo </label>
<a class="anchor-lbl" href="#">
  <h3 class="lbl2">18 Meses</h3>
</a>
```

He editado mi pregunta a lo que tengo hasta ahora, no tengo ningún error en consola, pero tampoco effecto al hacer mi hover

Comment: Ya te funcionó? has colocado mi respuesta como aceptada pero dices que sigues teniendo problemas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu código puedo ver que estás usando **jQuery**, entonces por que no lo usas para todo ? En vez de usar **JavaScript** nativo deberías de utilizar las utilidades que te ofrece **jQuery** para hacer este tipo de cosas con mayor facilidad.

```js
!function () {
  $(".anchor-lbl").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('bounce');
  }).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('bounce');
  })
}();
```

```css
.bounce{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="anchor-lbl">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="anchor-lbl">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="anchor-lbl">Link 3</a>
<a href="#" class="anchor-lbl">Link 4</a>
<a href="#" class="anchor-lbl">Link 5</a>
```

Comment: me gustó se ve muy coherente, pero cuando pongo el mouse encima nada pasa, tampoco me manda error a la terminal.

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim edita la pregunta y agrega tu código actual, algo debe estar pasando para que no veas la ejecución, si te fijas en el snippet si funciona

Comment: Ya quedò mil gracias